# Pip is not working - ImportError: No module named 'pip' - but I installed it

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have installed  pip and python 2.7 on my laptop. Whenever I try to install any new  package with pip it gives the following output and no package get installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

I have reinstalled it couple of  times it gives the same  output. I am new to ubuntu, Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Did you install pi p from the repositories or 3rd party source?

Comment: I checked out something. This command is working for installing package using pip :  sudo python -m pip install package-name

Comment: @karel I think the error message is clear, `pip` seems to be the 3.5 or 3.6 `pip` and he needs to use `pip2` instead, at least thats whats on my system the case. And the error message above as well reads `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py` but he wants to install packages for 2.7 I guess. He can easy find out which pip he uses by `pip -V`. But then I'm on artful which has dropped 2.7 completely. This is why I asked on which Ubuntu version he is. On artful pip is in `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

Comment: On artful: `pip -V` --> `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)` and `pip2 -V` --> `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)` and `which pip` --> `/usr/local/bin/pip` and `which pip2` --> `/usr/bin/pip2`. All stock installs from the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have manually installed pip to `/usr/local/bin/pip` however the default location for the pip executable file that is installed from the default Ubuntu 17.10 repositories (*python-pip*) is `/usr/bin/pip`. The command `sudo python -m pip install <package-name>` works but `sudo pip install <package-name>` doesn't work shows that your system's default version of Python recognizes the pip module, but the operating system doesn't recognize pip.

Python 2 is no longer installed by default in Ubuntu 17.10. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

This command will also install Python2.7 as a dependency.

If the above doesn't work create a symbolic link at `/usr/local/bin/pip` which references to file `/usr/bin/pip`.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip  
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip
```